# Exponential complexity for Timetable Generating program

Tags: java, iteration, backtracking, exponential, timetable

I'm writing a program that computes exhaustively all possible timetable combination with backtracking.

**When I write "Classe" I mean school class with Students ( I can't translate class)**

I have 10 school classes:

```
 public enum Classe{ IA, IIA, IIIA, IB, IIB, IIIB, IC, IIC, IIIC, IID };
```

and 24 Teachers.

A Teacher is an object with: Name, Subject, Free Day and a 
**Map with Pair: Classe, Number of Hours in this class**

My TimeTable look like this: [TimeTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT9Hf.jpg)

I use **Iterative BackTracking** to fill this table with Classes like "IA".

Each column represents the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th for each Day.

It fills a column when the Teacher in the row has hours in the class and is at school.

When it reaches the last hour of saturday, it starts with first day of next classe.

It tries ALL combination.

The problem is the exponentiality of the my algorithm. It takes a lot of time.

This is the code of my BackTracking; sorry for italian comments.

```
int lev = 0;
    boolean review = false;
    ArrayList<Classe> arrayClasse = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( Classe.values() ) );
    int nClasseActual = 0;
    if( arrayClasse.isEmpty() ){ System.err.println("There is not classe to assign!"); System.exit(-1); }
    Classe classe = arrayClasse.get(nClasseActual);     //Take first classe

    if ( !firstChoice( classe, lev) ){  //Make first choice
        System.err.println("There is not first choice for the class "+classe);
        return; 
    }//if
    while (lev >= -1){ 

        if( solComplete(liv) ){                 //If the level is the last,

            /**I place a classe and now I look for next*/
            if( arrayClasse.size()-1 > nClasseActual ){         //There is next classe
                nClasseActual++;
                classe = arrayClasse.get( nClasseActual );  //Take the next

                lev = -1;                   //Assign the next classe beginnig from lev -1 (next it will be increased)
                review = false;             //I go on without reviewing

            } else {                            //There is not next class, it was the last
                print();                
                review = true;                  //I will try other combinations
                lev++;
            }//if lit

        }else{
            liv++;                                  //Otherwise I increase level
            if( !firstChoice( classe, lev) )        //and I do the first choice of the next level
                review= true;                       //If it doesn't fit, I need to review
        }//else

        while( review && lev >= 0){             //while it doesn't fit
            lev--;                              //go back with levels
            if( lev == -1 ){

                /**I have no solutions going forward and I try to modify a previous classe*/
                if( nClasseActual > 0 ){    //There is a previous classe and I have to retry
                    nClasseActual--;
                    classe = arrayClasse.get(nClasseActual);
                    lev = DAYS_OF_WEEK * HOURS_OF_DAY -1;   //retry starting from last level of previous classe

                } else{                         //There is not previous classe
                    System.out.println("I finished combinations");
                    return;             //There is not any choice
                }//if lit

            }//if -1

            if( nextChoice(classe, lev) )   //Do next choice and
                review= false;                  //if it fits, I haven't to review
        }//while
    }//while
```

Can you suggest me a more efficient solution?
How can I reduce processing time?

Comment: Those comments are so helpfull as this is EN website.

Comment: Please try to use English names for your variables where possible, as this is an English-speaking site. Thank you.

Comment: Translated :) If there are misunderstandings tell me :)

Comment: I think this question should belong to [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If any doubt about this, you can read how to do a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), where says that the question should: ***Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included***. Hope they help you, and if you have any problem with your code, you can return here!

Comment: @Shirkam Agreed that this question seems to be a good fit on Code Review, but do not advise to post minimal example there. Code Review questions are best with real, complete, code. Ideally a copy/paste from the IDE.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger That was just to give a prove that **here** you should post problems, not code reviews. Obviously, is best to give real, complete code in Code review, they could find another bugs you have not seen.

Comment: This is only the Back Tracking part. The real problem is the complexity so I need an algorithm more efficient or a strategy. I can also post all classes but I will not help. I post only this part to make understable the problem.

Comment: @FabioMancuso what are *F.S* and *G.L.* in your time  table? And secondly, I dont get that the given time table is teacher's time table or class's time table. At a glance it seems like teacher's time table but then in `Teacher` object you are having only one subject. Then if its class TT than it doesnt make sense to write class name in TT

Comment: you can add a few constraints to make it efficient(though) no change in time complexity. like it doesnt make sense to have five classes of one subject on one day. so like allowing only one period per day per subject or giving break to teacher after every class to rest, so, a teacher cant have two continuous classes. Well during my school days, for first half classes there was only one subject's class during a particular period everyday. Like for example having first period of english everyday. Adding this constraint will help in decreasing the cases by **alot** so you might want to add it.